# USRP-B210 GPSDO will not lock

Tags: software-defined-radio, usrp

Hi I own a B210 and I have a GPSDO that's installed but I do not have the antenna yet. Can I use it as a 10MHz reference and PPS until I obtain the antenna?

Comment: Are you talking about a USRP B210?

Comment: Hello and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Comment: At David Yes and @rclocher3 Thank You!

Comment: @ShaneT that comment asking for clarification was a gentle hint to [edit] the question so it is complete. Assume comments disappear the moment someone reads them; they are not considered part of the Q&A, and are not persistent at all.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

But you don't win as much: the more modern B210 GPSDOs aren't *worlds* better than the standard integrated TCXO of the B210 is, anyway. So, I'd recommend using clock source = internal until you get an active antenna for your GPSDO.

Generally, if you know you can work with the lower frequency accuracy or timing, why even bother with a GPSDO? All real-world receivers need to do frequency recovery, anyway, even if they had GPSDOs – unless nothing in the environment moves.

Comment: But what commands do I use to do this? (Use my GSPDO 10mhz reference and 1PPS) Is this done by UHD automatically? Or must I implement this via some command? What command do I issue to see if the B210 is using the GPSDO as I want?

Comment: in essence `multi_usrp::set_clock_source`.